# Swipe to Refresh Layout android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

So I've implemented swipeRefresh Layout in my app but when I refresh it duplicates my items... so this is my xlm code

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ad_banner_container"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_fragments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and above my java code

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        loadFragments();
                        // This line is important as it explicitly
                        // refreshes only once
                        // If "true" it implicitly refreshes forever
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }

        );
```

and so the fragments load here

```
private void loadFragments(){
        fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        vp_fragments.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vp_fragments);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside on refresh clear the list or use set to keep unique elements, set will take less time complexity however for non primitive datatype you need to use comparable or comparator interface, LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order of elements. i.e elements are placed as they are inserted.

Comment: yes, but do you have any link where I can see this being implemented or where shows a step by step, sorry I'm new to mobile development